# Format a range of columns based on their title - Excel

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I've got part of a solution but it isn't working like I'd hope, so I've come to you for advice.

I regularly receive Excel files where I need to amend formatting. I'm trying to learn VBA by automating as much of these procedures as possible.

One particular format I complete is converting the date to "DDMMYYYY" (09091986), where it usually comes in as 09/09/1986.

Within my worksheet, there are a total of 3 columns containing dates, all of which need the same formatting and all of which have the word "DATE" in the heading. They are not adjacent to each other.

I must also be careful not to have any other data affected, as I have names and addresses which may contain the characters "DATE".

So, background out of the way... I'm trying to search the first row until I find the word "Date" and then format that for each cell until the last row, before moving on to the next column containing the word "DATE" and repeating this until all columns with the word "DATE" have been formatted.

I'm sure you have a simple solution but I can't seem to find it myself.

Here is the code I have...

```
Sub Dateformat()
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim FindCol As Integer
    Dim C1 As Integer

    LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    FindCol = Cells.Find(What:="DATE", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Column

    For C1 = 2 To LastRow
            Cells(C1, FindCol).NumberFormat = "DDMMYYYY"
    Next C1

End Sub
```

This works for the first column containing date but doesn't move on to the next column.

Thanks for the help

Regards,
Adam

Comment: are there any other **column headers** that may have the word date in them besides the 3 you need to format?

Comment: Why not just use a custom format: `ddmmyy`?  No need for vba.  Highlight the columns desired and apply custom format.

Comment: No, we're safe to use "Date" for the columns as there will not be any other columns with a header containing "Date".

Comment: thanks @AdamBlunt. See my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, you need to loop through and find each Row Header with `DATE`

Here is one way to do it.

```
Sub Dateformat()

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim FindCol As Range
    Dim sAdd As String

    Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' adjust as needed
    
    With wks
    
        LastRow = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

        'find first instance where DATE exists in row 1 (headers)
        Set FindCol = .Rows(1).Find(What:="DATE", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
                    False, SearchFormat:=False)
                    
        'store address of first found instance (to check in loop)
        sAdd = FindCol.Address
        
        Do
        
            'format column (row 2 to last used row)
            .Range(.Cells(2, FindCol.Column), .Cells(LastRow, FindCol.Column)).NumberFormat = "DDMMYYYY"
            'this line works as well and is a bit cleaner
            '.Cells(2, FindCol.Column).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).NumberFormat = "DDMMYYYY"                

            'find next instance (begin search after current instance found)
            Set FindCol = .Cells.FindNext(After:=FindCol)
            
        'keep going until nothing is found or the loop finds the first address again (in which case the code can stop)
        Loop Until FindCol Is Nothing Or FindCol.Address = sAdd
    
    End With
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This achieves exactly what I was hoping for and the annotation is ideal for someone like me who is trying to learn VBA. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Great. Glad to help @AdamBlunt! If this solved your problem, please mark as answered.

Comment: Done. If I had better reputation I'd mark it useful too.

Comment: Appreciate it. Best to you in your coding endeavors @AdamBlunt :)